# Can't delete the cache in xperia mini

Tags: android, caching, video

I am  playing video so it cache lot of data. I can't delete the cache in xperia mini in others phone it is working fine.

I tried

```
mWebview.clearCache(true);
```

and

```
File cacheDir = this.getCacheDir();
File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
   for (File file : files)
        file.delete();
    }
```

But always getting error in log-cat:

```
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewWorkerThread
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1640)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.clearCache(WebViewDatabase.java:707)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.webkit.CacheManager.clearCache(CacheManager.java:582)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:194)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-18 10:31:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```